# REST Easy Webservice

Tags: rest, thread-safety, resteasy

Hi I have Implemented a RESTful webservice using JBOSS-Rest Easy.

Each REST service has instance variable which provides service methods.

Does having instance variables make  restful web services thread unsafe ?

Is there any thing else i need to do to make them ThreadSafe ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does having instance variables make restful web services thread
>   unsafe?

No, having instance variables does not make your Resteasy resources unsafe.  Resteasy resources are created on a per-request basis by default.